# C++ getline and gcount

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an `std::istream` pointing to the following contents (the line break is a `'\n'` character):

```
12345678
9
```

and run the following code:

```
std::istream & is = ...
char buff[9];
is.getline(buff, 9);
int n = is.gcount();
```

Now `n == 8` and `strcmp(buff, "12345678") == 0`. The question is, how do I know that I read the entire line instead of some of the line?

If the steam instead points to the following contents:

```
123456789
0
```

and the same code is executed, I am still on the same line. How do I differentiate between these two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to your answer is in your question

```
is.getline(buff, 9);
int n = is.gcount();
Now n == 8
```

According to the [reference for getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/), it will extract up to `n - 1` characters -- in your case, up to 8.  This is slightly misleading, because if the nth character is the delimiter, it will also be extracted (but not copied to the buffer).  More importantly, if you have NOT reached the delimiter before reaching `n` characters, this piece is relevant:

```
If the function stops reading because this size (n) is reached,
the failbit internal flag is set
```

So, in short, if the fail bit is set, you're still on the same line (and you'll have to clear the state in order to continue processing the istream).  Sometimes, eof will also set the fail bit.  So you probably want to check if the state is failbit and only failbit:

```
if ( is.rdstate() == std::ios::failbit ) {
  std::cout << "Filled the buffer, but did NOT finish the line\n";
  is.clear();
}
```

Comment: Should it be `&` and not `==`?

Comment: I initially had `&`, but changed it to `==`.  It's possible for the failbit to be set under other circumstances (eof, e.g.), and that would also set eofbit.  So, I think `==` is the right choice here.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::string` and the free `std::getline` function:

```
#include <istream>
#include <string>

// ...

std::istream & is = ...;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(is, line))
{
  // process line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the next character.  If it is a newline, you have read all the data on the line.

BTW, popular usage is to read the entire line, up to the newline, into an `std::string`, then process the string.